# how to achieve a horizontal jQuery slider effect

Tags: jquery

I have a list of html `<li>` elements, I want this to scroll horizontally with jQuery and to have the current date displaying bigger, this is something that I could do the text effects but I have no clue how to go about coding a horizontal slider.

Saying that all I have so far is the below or view a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBetR/)

```
<div class="yearswrapper">
    <ul class="yearslist">
        <li><a href="">2003</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2004</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2005</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2006</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2007</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2008</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2009</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2010</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2011</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2012</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2013</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="left">Slide Left</p>
    <p id="right">Slide right</p>
</div>
```

css.css

```
.yearslist li {
     display:inline;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried until now? This Links to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) are a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `jQuery` slider: http://jqueryui.com/slider/ ( make sure you download jQuery, jQuery UI and the UI CSS ).

Once you have a working slider, there is an event called `slide`. Each time a user changes the value of the slider, it checks against this slide event. The concept is that you would check against the value of the `slide` event and change the `CSS` accordingly.

```
$( '#slider' ).slider({
    value: 1, // start at first li
    step: 1,  // slider moves up and down one to check each year
    max: 13,  // end at year 2013
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        //check against the ui.value and change CSS
        $( 'li' ).eq( ui.value ).css( 'font-weight', 'bold' );
    }
})
```

There is more documentation on the `jQuery` slider here: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: ok just been reading over this and to be fair seems like the best solution at the moment. thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

If you use overflow on 'yearswrapper' you can get an horizontal scrollbar to appear. You can then position the scroll bar - this page maybe of some help:

http://api.jquery.com/?s=scroll

or this may help:

[Crossbrowser content scroller with custom look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032693/crossbrowser-content-scroller-with-custom-look)